# How to select all elements of the same class before

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<div class="htx">
    <div>string</div>
</div>
<div class="htx">
    <div>string</div>
</div>
<div class="htx">
    <div>otherString</div>
</div>
<div class="htx">
    <div>string</div>
</div>
```

I want to select all htx class elements before that one which contains otherString

```
var res = $('.htx:contains("otherString")');
var sec = res.prevAll();
```

This didn't work.

Comment: Work fine : http://jsfiddle.net/g5rbxncs/ . Are you waiting the DOM to be ready?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle or stacksnippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var res = $('.htx:contains("otherString")');
var sec = res.prevAll('.htx');
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkt2c0Lx/1/) (with the exact code from the question + console.log)

Works as expected, the `console.log(sec.toArray());` shows 2 divs you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Like that,

```
var res = $('.htx div:contains(otherString)');
var sec = res.prevAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript you can do this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/1emyx6yr/)

```
var all = document.getElementsByClassName('htx');
for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    if (all[i].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML == 'otherString') {
        break
    } else {
        all[i].style.backgroundColor = 'sienna';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in jquery:

```
var l = $(".htx").lenght;
var elements ="";
for(var i=i; i<=l; i++)
{
    if($(".htx:nth-child('" + i + "')").children("div").text() == "otherString")
        break;
    else
        elements += $(".htx:nth-child('+i+')");
}
```

Hope this helps.